# Using computed column in .net core

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am trying to use computed column in my project, but I am facing the some error.

> Column 'inserted.TotalMarks' cannot be referenced in the OUTPUT clause because the column definition contains a subquery or references a function that performs user or system data access. A function is assumed by default to perform data access if it is not schemabound. Consider removing the subquery or function from the column definition or removing the column from the OUTPUT clause.

Model

```
public partial class LMS_SurveyUser
    {
        public LMS_SurveyUser()
        {

        }
        [Key]
        public int SurveyUserID { get; set; }
        public int SurveyID { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public bool? IsCompleted { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ExpiryDate { get; set; }
        public int? MarksObtained { get; set; }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public int? TotalMarks { get; set; }
        public int LastPageAccessed { get; set; }
        public int? WhoCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime? WhenCreated { get; set; }
        public int? WhoModified { get; set; }
        public DateTime? WhenModified { get; set; }

    }
```

While creating the record with above mentioned it does not gives any error, but if I try to update the existing record then it gives the above mentioned error.

I have configured SQL function in the database for column 'TotalMarks'. I have tried with the fluent mapping also, but it gives the same error.

And in the 'TotalMarks' computed column specification I write this formula:

```
([dbo].[LMSFN_CalculateTotalMark]([SurveyID],[UserID]))
```

I am inserting/updating record like below,

Inserting Record

```
public void InsertSurveyUserDetails(LMS_SurveyUser model)
{
    dbcontext.Add(model);
    dbcontext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Updating Record

```
public void UpdateSurveyUserDetails(LMS_SurveyUser model)
{
    dbcontext.Update(model);
    dbcontext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Any help on this appreciated !

Comment: It looks like computed columns need to be configured through the Fluent API - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/computed-columns).

Comment: @steamrolla. Yeah I have tried with that way also, getting same error. Also, in fluent mapping how can I configure the sql function with parameters for computed column ?

Comment: Remove the data annotation on `TotalMarks` in your model.
What does your Context's OnModelCreating look like? According to those docs, should look something like this:
    `modelBuilder.Entity<LMS_SurveyUser>()
        .Property(u => u.TotalMarks)
        .HasComputedColumnSql("[dbo].[LMSFN_CalculateTotalMark]([SurveyID],[UserID])");`

Comment: What version of .Net Core are you using? It was a bug with `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed` and was fixed in `1.1.0-preview1` https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6044

Comment: @steamrolla yes I have written down the same in context as you have mentioned

Comment: what version of EF Core are you on? See @J.Doe's link.